# Present solutions for testing Android applications

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I've just reviewed about 10 Android books, read a bunch of articles and found a couple of frameworks, but still I haven't found any comprehensive way of testing Android applications.
It's too bad that testing appears (if at all) only as a single and short chapter only  in some books.

There are:

- [ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html) and [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html)
- [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)
- [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

But none of them has sufficient documentation, tutorials or example. I couldn't able to setup Robotium with Gradle as well to be run either from AS or even command line.

What is the most current way to test Android applications with `Android Studio 1.0` and `Gradle 1.0.0`? What frameworks and tools do you use? Where do you learn testing recipes for Android?

The only thing I managed to setup is [standard android ways for testing applications](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/index.html), however there are only few examples how to do that.

Comment: Recently Google released a bunch of tutorial with Udacity, I think they have covered this also.

Comment: That should be reasonable, right? Guess what? No testing covered there! :( Oh maybe except DB testing, which is mundane. https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/blob/clean-history/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/test/TestDb.java

Comment: Robolectric seems still only supports API 18. Maybe Kitkat support is coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, there is no single page, that covers all Android test frameworks. Anyway there are more of them than you listed above.

- [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso)
- [UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) and [related page](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)
- [Calabash gh project](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) and [official page](http://calaba.sh/)
- [Appium gh project](https://github.com/appium/appium) and [official page](http://appium.io/)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/mobile-testing)

I don't know much about integrating them with Android Studio as it still is in infancy, however it should be feasible.

Comment: That's what I found too. I wonder what people use right now, which of them are well supported and maintained, which have comprehensive examples and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Blundell's blog for some good tutorials: [here's the one for espresso](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-espresso-instrumentation-tests/). Be warned, while I could get Espresso and JUnit tests to work, I haven't managed to get Robolectric to work yet. If anyone has a way to get it to work for projects targetting API 21, I would be keen to know how.